# M2.4 - How to add OG tag for categories?

Tags: category, products, magento2.3.4, home-page, open-graph

I am created OG tag for the Homepage and products,

**For Homepage :**

**1)app/design/frontend/Zero/my_theme/Magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<meta name="og:title" content="Welcome to our store"/>
<meta name="og:description" content="Buy Online - Best price/>
```

**For Products :**

**2)app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\opengraph\general.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>

<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title"
      content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"
      content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"
      content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()) ?>" />
<?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()) :?>
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($priceAmount) ?>"/>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

and added **general.phtml** into

**3) app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_opengraph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <attribute name="prefix" value="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="opengraph.general" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/general.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="opengraph.currency" as="meta.currency" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/opengraph/currency.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**4)How to do it for all categories?**

Answer (score 1):

Create the following layout file

```
app\design\frontend\my_theme\Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="opengraph.category" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/view/opengraph/category.phtml"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

in catalog/view/opengraph/category.phtml add the og headers you want for your category pages i.e.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"
      content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getCurrentCategory()->getMetaTitle()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getCurrentCategory()->getUrl()) ?>" />
```

Comment: May i know my path right : app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\opengraph\category.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ready-made extension by which you can add the OG tags on any page from Admin.
extension link: https://magefan.com/magento-2-open-graph-extension-og-tags/?aff=9c677bd9ead4ea4926c59a7d0467881d